# Android Compose with single event

Tags: android, events, state, android-jetpack-compose, snackbar

Right now I have an Event class in the ViewModel that is exposed as a Flow this way:

```
abstract class BaseViewModel() : ViewModel() {

    ...

    private val eventChannel = Channel<Event>(Channel.BUFFERED)
    val eventsFlow = eventChannel.receiveAsFlow()

    fun sendEvent(event: Event) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            eventChannel.send(event)
        }
    }

    sealed class Event {
        data class NavigateTo(val destination: Int): Event()
        data class ShowSnackbarResource(val resource: Int): Event()
        data class ShowSnackbarString(val message: String): Event()
    }
}
```

And this is the composable managing it:

```
@Composable
fun SearchScreen(
    viewModel: SearchViewModel
) {
    val events = viewModel.eventsFlow.collectAsState(initial = null)
    val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(all = 24.dp)
        ) {
            SearchHeader(viewModel = viewModel)
            SearchContent(
                viewModel = viewModel,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 24.dp)
            )
            when(events.value) {
                is NavigateTo -> TODO()
                is ShowSnackbarResource -> {
                    val resources = LocalContext.current.resources
                    val message = (events.value as ShowSnackbarResource).resource
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                            message = resources.getString(message)
                        )
                    }
                }
                is ShowSnackbarString -> {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                            message = (events.value as ShowSnackbarString).message
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        SnackbarHost(
            hostState = snackbarHostState,
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
        )
    }
}
```

I followed the pattern for single events with Flow from [here](https://proandroiddev.com/android-singleliveevent-redux-with-kotlin-flow-b755c70bb055).

My problem is, the event is handled correctly only the first time (SnackBar is shown correctly). But after that, seems like the events are not collected anymore. At least until I leave the screen and come back. And in that case, all events are triggered consecutively.

Can't see what I'm doing wrong. When debugged, events are sent to the Channel correctly, but seems like the state value is not updated in the composable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure how you manage to compile the code, because I get an error on `launch`.

> Calls to launch should happen inside a LaunchedEffect and not composition

Usually you can use `LaunchedEffect` which is already running in the coroutine scope, so you don't need `coroutineScope.launch`. Read more about side effects in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects).

A little kotlin advice: when using `when` in types, you don't need to manually cast the variable to a type with `as`. In cases like this, you can declare `val` along with your variable to prevent `Smart cast to ... is impossible, because ... is a property that has open or custom getter` error:

```kotlin
val resources = LocalContext.current.resources
val event = events.value // allow Smart cast
LaunchedEffect(event) {
    when (event) {
        is BaseViewModel.Event.NavigateTo -> TODO()
        is BaseViewModel.Event.ShowSnackbarResource -> {
            val message = event.resource
            snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                message = resources.getString(message)
            )
        }
        is BaseViewModel.Event.ShowSnackbarString -> {
            snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                message = event.message
            )
        }
    }
}
```

This code has one problem: if you send the same event many times, it will not be shown because `LaunchedEffect` will not be restarted: `event` as key is the same.

You can solve this problem in different ways. Here are some of them:

1. Replace `data class` with `class`: now events will be compared by pointer, not by fields.
2. Add a random id to the data class, so that each new element is not equal to another:

   ```kotlin
   data class ShowSnackbarResource(val resource: Int, val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID()) : Event()
   ```

Note that the coroutine `LaunchedEffect` will be canceled when a new event occurs. And since `showSnackbar` is a suspend function, the previous snackbar will be hidden to display the new one. If you run `showSnackbar` on `coroutineScope.launch` (still doing it inside `LaunchedEffect`), the new snackbar will wait until the previous snackbar disappears before it appears.

Another option, which seems cleaner to me, is to reset the state of the event because you have already reacted to it. You can add another event to do this:

```kotlin
object Clean : Event()
```

And send it after the snackbar disappears:

```kotlin
LaunchedEffect(event) {
    when (event) {
        is BaseViewModel.Event.NavigateTo -> TODO()
        is BaseViewModel.Event.ShowSnackbarResource -> {
            val message = event.resource
            snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                message = resources.getString(message)
            )
        }
        is BaseViewModel.Event.ShowSnackbarString -> {
            snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                message = event.message
            )
        }
        null, BaseViewModel.Event.Clean -> return@LaunchedEffect
    }
    viewModel.sendEvent(BaseViewModel.Event.Clean)
}
```

But in this case, if you send the same event while the previous one has not yet disappeared, it will be ignored as before. This can be perfectly normal, depending on the structure of your application, but to prevent this you can show it on `coroutineScope` as before.

Also, check out the more general solution implemented in the [JetNews](https://github.com/android/compose-samples) compose app example. I suggest you download the project and inspect it starting from [location](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/b0922b3ea6658b8721be84de0a946b3e78064587/JetNews/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetnews/ui/home/HomeScreen.kt#L211) where the snackbar is displayed.

Answer (score 22):

Rather than placing your logic right inside composable place them inside

```
// Runs only on initial composition 
LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
  viewModel.eventsFlow.collectLatest { value -> 
    when(value) {
       // Handle events
    }
 }
}
```

And also rather than using it as state just collect value from flow in `LaunchedEffect` block. This is how I implemented single event in my application

Answer (score 13):

Here's a modified version of Jack's answer, as an extension function following new guidelines for [safer flow collection](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/a-safer-way-to-collect-flows-from-android-uis-23080b1f8bda).

```
@Composable
inline fun <reified T> Flow<T>.observeWithLifecycle(
    lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current,
    minActiveState: Lifecycle.State = Lifecycle.State.STARTED,
    noinline action: suspend (T) -> Unit
) {
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
        lifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            flowWithLifecycle(lifecycleOwner.lifecycle, minActiveState).collect(action)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
viewModel.flow.observeWithLifecycle { value ->
    //Use the collected value
}
```

Comment: i get an error on `collect(action)`. it says "required: FlowCollector<T>. found: suspend (T) -> Unit"

Comment: from the medium article: "Notice that you need to remember the flow that is aware of the lifecycle with locationFlow and lifecycleOwner as keys to always use the same flow unless one of the keys change." maybe i'm missing something because i have no experience with inline functions, but i dont see that part implemented in your function

Comment: @or_dvir There are two `collect` functions. You should use the one which accepts `crossinline action: suspend (value: T) -> Unit` as parameter. And regarding your second question, `LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit)` pretty much does the same thing.

Comment: i did not see another fucntion... maybe its a version thing?
LaunchedEffect(key = Unit) means it will run only on first composition, and never updated. if anything, shouldnt the key be the life cycle aware flow?

Comment: @or_dvir Mabye it's a version thing, I have no idea. I think that would be necessary only if there's the possibility of the flow being changed, in that case yeah it makes sense to remember the flow. But if you're just using a single specific flow to send your single time events, then you should be fine with `LaunchedEffect`.

Comment: If you've got en error on `collect(action)`, just import `import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect`. @or_dvir

Comment: I believe it's deprecated in latest (1.6.2) coroutines version, see `Collect.kt`: ```@Deprecated(level = DeprecationLevel.HIDDEN, message = "Backwards compatibility with JS and K/N")
public suspend inline fun <T> Flow<T>.collect(crossinline action: suspend (value: T) -> Unit)```. But I think `.collect { action(it) }` will work the same way

Comment: Why `lifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch` is needed? I think it's redundant and caused duplicate emissions for me, when navigating back to the screen.

Comment: @JokubasTrinkunas @Soroush Lotfi Yeah, it's causing duplication of the event emissions for me either (this part is redundant: `lifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch`)

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/Kotlin-Android-Open-Source/Jetpack-Compose-MVI-Coroutines-Flow/blob/master/core-ui/src/main/java/com/hoc/flowmvi/core_ui/rememberFlowWithLifecycle.kt

```kotlin
@Suppress("ComposableNaming")
@Composable
fun <T> Flow<T>.collectInLaunchedEffectWithLifecycle(
  vararg keys: Any?,
  lifecycle: Lifecycle = LocalLifecycleOwner.current.lifecycle,
  minActiveState: Lifecycle.State = Lifecycle.State.STARTED,
  collector: suspend CoroutineScope.(T) -> Unit
) {
  val flow = this
  val currentCollector by rememberUpdatedState(collector)

  LaunchedEffect(flow, lifecycle, minActiveState, *keys) {
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main.immediate) {
      lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(minActiveState) {
        flow.collect { currentCollector(it) }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```kotlin
class ViewModel {
  val singleEvent: Flow<E> = eventChannel.receiveAsFlow()
}

@Composable fun Demo() {
  val snackbarHostState by rememberUpdatedState(LocalSnackbarHostState.current)
  val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
  viewModel.singleEvent.collectInLaunchedEffectWithLifecycle { event ->
    when (event) {
      SingleEvent.Refresh.Success -> {
        scope.launch {
          snackbarHostState.showSnackbar("Refresh successfully")
        }
      }
      is SingleEvent.Refresh.Failure -> {
        scope.launch {
          snackbarHostState.showSnackbar("Failed to refresh")
        }
      }
      is SingleEvent.GetUsersError -> {
        scope.launch {
          snackbarHostState.showSnackbar("Failed to get users")
        }
      }
      is SingleEvent.RemoveUser.Success -> {
        scope.launch {
          snackbarHostState.showSnackbar("Removed '${event.user.fullName}'")
        }
      }
      is SingleEvent.RemoveUser.Failure -> {
        scope.launch {
          snackbarHostState.showSnackbar("Failed to remove '${event.user.fullName}'")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: great code sir.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version of Soroush Lotfi answer making sure we also stop flow collection whenever the composable is not visible anymore: just replace the `LaunchedEffect` with a `DisposableEffect`

```
@Composable
inline fun <reified T> Flow<T>.observeWithLifecycle(
    lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current,
    minActiveState: Lifecycle.State = Lifecycle.State.STARTED,
    noinline action: suspend (T) -> Unit
) {
    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        val job = lifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
           flowWithLifecycle(lifecycleOwner.lifecycle, minActiveState).collect(action)
        }

        onDispose {
            job.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not better than the solution Soroush Lotfi, it does the same, but requires unnecessary `onDispose` call :). Flow collection will be stopped anyways when lifecycle active state changes, so this cancellation of the job is redundant imho.

Comment: I agree that 'flowWithLifecycle' will take care of starting, stoping, restarting the flow. However, the LaunchedEffect will be triggered on each initial composition. E.g. when navigating away from a screen & back again we're ADDING a flow-collector each time.

Comment: Yes, `LaunchedEffect` will be triggered on each initial composition, but I think `DisposableEffect` too, if it's called in the scope of your screen composable. AFAIK, the only difference between these two, is that `DisposableEffect` has a method for clean-up, which is not needed here, since the collection will be cancelled anyway when the screen is destroyed.